# Whatsapp-web js doesn't fire ready event

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

Whatsapp-web js doesn’t fire ready event and other only fire Qr event. I alos scan and authenticate the whatsapp correctly. but not working ready event.

```
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
var qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', (qr) => {
qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
console.log('QR RECEIVED');
});

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.initialize();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was fixed my issue

npm r whatsapp-web.js

set this version in package.json
"whatsapp-web.js": "https://github.com/Julzk/whatsapp-web.js/tarball/jkr_hotfix_7"

npm install

Comment: also we can fix this issue with this version 1.22.2-alpha.0. Try npm i whatsapp-web.js@1.22.2-alpha.0

Comment: Helped me. The official website doesn't tell it, such a huge mistake. https://wwebjs.dev/

Comment: 1.22.2-alpha.0 does not contain the fix, at least not when I tested

Comment: im using 1.22.2-alpha.0 and still not receive client ready message. but when im trying use "whatsapp-web.js": "https://github.com/Julzk/whatsapp-web.js/tarball/jkr_hotfix_7" has been work. thankyou

Answer (score 7):

I found in the official github the fix the issue, the solution is here:
in summary you need to modify the file `client.js` in the `node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/client.js`

change the line 175 replace this:

```
 const INTRO_IMG_SELECTOR = 'div[role=\'textbox\']'; //'[data-icon=\'chat\']';
```

https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/2473

Comment: it works for me, version 1.22.1

Comment: yes this way is also working..